# Turning powers into an explicit product

Tags: products

I have  the following nested list

```
{{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 5]^2}, {1}, {yy[1, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}}
```

with objects yy[#1,#2] and I wish to get rid of the powers ^2 and ^3; writing them as an explicit product, i.e. I want the result to be

```
{{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 5] yy[2, 5]}, {1},
 {yy[1, 5] yy[1, 5] yy[1, 5] yy[2, 3] yy[2, 3]}}
```

Comment: A space in *Mathematica* usually implies multiplication. If you are just wanting it for looks purposes, you can use `/. Power[f_, e_] :> Row[ConstantArray[f, e]]` to replicate what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it isn't just for looks, I would still need the space to represent multiplication because I will end up using /. Times -> List. (I'd like a comma in between each product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identical multiplicands are automatically converted into powers:

```
foo*foo*bar
```

> ```
> bar foo^2
> ```

To prevent this you either need to prevent evaluation as with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html):

```
HoldForm[foo*foo*bar]
```

> ```
> foo foo bar      (* HoldForm still present but not displayed *)
> ```

Or you need to define your own display method for `Power` which is essentially what [kale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1560/kale) proposes in a comment:

```
foo*foo*bar /. Power[m_, x_] :> Row[ConstantArray[m, x], " "]
```

> ```
> bar foo foo
> ```

---

In a comment you write:

> I would still need the space to represent multiplication because I will end up using /. Times -> List. (I'd like a comma in between each product)

Please tell me if this meets your goal:

```
expr = {{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[1, 3] yy[2, 3] yy[2, 5]^2}, {1},
        {yy[1, 5] yy[2, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}};

expr /. {Times -> Sequence, Power -> Apply[Sequence]@*ConstantArray}
```

> ```
> {{yy[1, 4], yy[2, 7]}, {yy[1, 3], yy[2, 3], yy[2, 5], yy[2, 5]}, {1},
>  {yy[1, 5], yy[2, 3], yy[2, 3], yy[2, 5], yy[2, 5], yy[2, 5]}}
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have a slight issue using this code. The problem with doing Times -> List before your code is it puts an extra set of curly brackets around elements which have a multplication with a space.{{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 
      5]^2}, {1}, {yy[1, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}}   /. Times -> List gives extra curly brackets for the first and last element of this list which I don't really want. So after applying your code, I get different levels of nested lists.

Comment: {{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 
      5]^2}, {1}, {yy[1, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}}   /. Times -> List /. 
 Power -> Apply[Sequence]@*ConstantArray } give too many curly brackets in the first and last elements. My end result should be {{yy[1, 4], yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 5], 
yy[2, 5]}, {1}, {yy[1, 5],yy[1, 5],yy[1, 5], yy[2, 3], 
   yy[2, 3]}}

Comment: This wasn't an issue when I had elements lists with no powers, because I would just do /. Times -> List and Flatten as necessary, usually Flatten[%,1]

Comment: @user1523500 Rather convoluted but does this do what you want (in other cases as well)?:  `{{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[2, 5]^2}, {1}, {yy[1, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}} /. 
    Times -> AngleBracket /. Power -> ConstantArray /. 
  AngleBracket -> Join //. {{x__}} :> {x}`  If so I can try to refine it.

Comment: Not quite, that merged the numbers in brackets of the first expression for some reason, giving yy[1,4,2,7]. I think I found something that works, although it probably isn't that efficient, it uses your code, strings and I made the list more complicated to make sure it covers all cases I need: `{ {{yy[1, 4] yy[2, 7]}, {yy[1, 3] yy[2, 3] yy[2, 5]^2}, {1}, {yy[1, 5] yy[2, 5]^3 yy[2, 3]^2}} /. Times -> AngleBracket /. Power -> Apply[Sequence]@*ConstantArray; StringReplace[ StringReplace[ToString[%], "[LeftAngleBracket]" -> ""], "[RightAngleBracket]" -> ""]; gg = ToExpression[%] `

Comment: @user1523500 Oops, sorry.  Okay, I'll have to return to this tomorrow.

Comment: That should give the correct end result, I wonder if there is a quicker way to get this result?

Comment: @user1523500 Please see my updated answer and tell me if it now works.  If not please include some examples where it fails in the question, along with the output for those examples that you desire.

Comment: I think that's  much cleaner indeed! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user1523500 You're welcome.